# Web scraper to retrieve articles from HTML embedded in JavaScript

Tags: rust, web-scraping

I wrote a web scraper library to parse articles from HTML documents where they are encoded in a JSON object in JavaScript element.
I wrote the example HTML file and `main.rs` so that you can test the library here for review. The subject of the review should only be `lib.rs`.

`./Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "webscraper"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
build_html = "2.4.0"
once_cell = "1.18.0"
rslint_parser = "0.3.1"
serde = "1.0.164"
serde_derive = "1.0.164"
serde_json = "1.0.96"
scraper = "0.16.0"
```

`./src/lib.js`

```rust
use build_html::{Container, ContainerType, HtmlContainer, HtmlPage};
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;
use rslint_parser::{parse_text, SyntaxKind::SEMICOLON};
use scraper::{ElementRef, Html, Selector};
use serde_derive::Deserialize;
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter};
use std::str::FromStr;

const LEADING_JS_TOKENS: [&str; 2] = ["article", "="];
static SCRIPT_SELECTOR: Lazy<Selector> =
    Lazy::new(|| Selector::parse("script#article").expect("could not build script selector"));

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Article {
    headline: String,
    #[serde(rename = "sub_headline")]
    subtitle: String,
    elements: Vec<Element>,
}

impl build_html::Html for Article {
    fn to_html_string(&self) -> String {
        let mut div = Container::new(ContainerType::Div)
            .with_attributes([("class", "w3-container")])
            .with_header(1, &self.headline)
            .with_header(2, &self.subtitle);

        for element in &self.elements {
            element.add_to_html(&mut div);
        }

        HtmlPage::new()
            .with_title(&self.headline)
            .with_head_link("w3.css", "stylesheet")
            .with_meta([
                ("name", "viewport"),
                ("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"),
            ])
            .with_container(div)
            .to_html_string()
    }
}

impl FromStr for Article {
    type Err = serde_json::Error;

    fn from_str(json: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        serde_json::from_str::<Self>(json)
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Element {
    #[serde(rename = "type")]
    typ: String,
    text: Option<String>,
}

impl Element {
    pub fn add_to_html(&self, parent: &mut impl HtmlContainer) {
        if let Some(ref text) = self.text {
            match self.typ.as_str() {
                "header" => parent.add_header(3, text),
                "text" => parent.add_paragraph_attr(text, [("align", "justify")]),
                _ => (),
            };
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum ScrapingError {
    CouldNotDeserializeJSON(serde_json::Error),
    JSONNotFound,
    ScriptElementNotFound,
}

impl Display for ScrapingError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(
            f,
            "{}",
            match self {
                Self::CouldNotDeserializeJSON(_) => "Could not deserialize JSON string",
                Self::JSONNotFound => "Could not find JSON object",
                Self::ScriptElementNotFound => "Could not find the script element",
            }
        )
    }
}

impl build_html::Html for ScrapingError {
    fn to_html_string(&self) -> String {
        let mut container = Container::new(ContainerType::Div)
            .with_attributes([("class", "w3-container w3-center")])
            .with_header(1, self.to_string());

        if let Self::CouldNotDeserializeJSON(error) = self {
            container.add_paragraph(format!("{}", error))
        }

        HtmlPage::new()
            .with_title("Error parsing article!")
            .with_head_link("w3.css", "stylesheet")
            .with_container(container)
            .to_html_string()
    }
}

pub fn scrape(text: &str) -> Result<Article, ScrapingError> {
    Article::from_str(
        &extract_json(
            find_script(&Html::parse_document(text)).ok_or(ScrapingError::ScriptElementNotFound)?,
        )
        .ok_or(ScrapingError::JSONNotFound)?,
    )
    .map_err(ScrapingError::CouldNotDeserializeJSON)
}

fn extract_json(script: ElementRef) -> Option<String> {
    for element in parse_text(&script.text().collect::<String>(), 0)
        .syntax()
        .children()
    {
        if element
            .descendants_with_tokens()
            .filter_map(|element| element.into_token())
            .zip(LEADING_JS_TOKENS)
            .all(|(token, name)| token.text() == name)
        {
            return Some(
                element
                    .descendants_with_tokens()
                    .filter_map(|element| element.into_token())
                    .skip(LEADING_JS_TOKENS.len())
                    .take_while(|token| token.kind() != SEMICOLON)
                    .map(|token| token.to_string())
                    .collect(),
            );
        }
    }

    None
}

fn find_script(html: &Html) -> Option<ElementRef> {
    html.select(&SCRIPT_SELECTOR).next()
}
```

`./src/main.rs`

```rust
use std::fs::read_to_string;
use webscraper::scrape;

const HTML_FILE: &str = "./example.html";

fn main() {
    let html = read_to_string(HTML_FILE).expect("Could not read HTML file.");
    let article = scrape(html.as_str()).expect("Could not scrape article.");
    println!("{:?}", article);
}
```

`./example.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script id="article">
const STUFF_I_DO_NOT_NEED = "blah";
article={
    "headline": "The headline.",
    "sub_headline": "This subtitle.",
    "elements": [
        {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "Frobnicate the fizzbuzz!"
        },
        {
            "type": "header",
            "text": "Paragraph title"
        },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "Paragraph content..."
        }
    ]
};
const MORE_STUFF_I_DO_NOT_NEED = 42;
</script>
```

I'd like to have feedback on the implementation of the library.