# Enum to deserialize HTML sizes from JSON with serde

Tags: json, rust, web-scraping

I added an enum for my [webscraper](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/285561/web-scraper-to-retrieve-articles-from-html-embedded-in-javascript) to deserialize data from a JSON field that represents an HTML image size, which can either be an unsigned int like `1080` or a string like `"100%"`:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter};

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub enum HtmlSize {
    String(String),
    Int(u64),
}

impl Display for HtmlSize {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Self::String(string) => write!(f, r#""{}""#, string),
            Self::Int(int) => write!(f, "{}", int),
        }
    }
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for HtmlSize {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        deserializer.deserialize_any(HtmlSizeVisitor)
    }
}

struct HtmlSizeVisitor;

impl<'de> serde::de::Visitor<'de> for HtmlSizeVisitor {
    type Value = HtmlSize;

    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(
            formatter,
            "an unsigned integer or a string representing a width"
        )
    }

    fn visit_u64<E: serde::de::Error>(self, n: u64) -> Result<HtmlSize, E> {
        Ok(HtmlSize::Int(n))
    }

    fn visit_str<E: serde::de::Error>(self, string: &str) -> Result<HtmlSize, E> {
        Ok(HtmlSize::String(string.to_string()))
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct ImageInfo {
    id: String,
    alt: String,
    height: HtmlSize,
    src: String,
    width: HtmlSize,
    caption: String,
    credit: String,
}
```

I did not find anything readily available like this, so I implemented the above `HtmlSize` with its corresponding visitor. Is this a sensible implementation or did I reinvent the wheel? Can the implementation be improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need to implement your own logic, you can use `#[serde(untagged)`:

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Eq, PartialEq, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum HtmlSize {
    String(String),
    Int(u64),
}
```

`#[serde(untagged)]` will deserialize into which enum variant matches the incoming data.

Comment: Ha. I knew that I missed something. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough experience with rust in particular to usefully comment on the implementation itself

Still, there's one part of the *design* that I do think I can talk about - I expect that an image with `width: "hello"` is not, and should never be, considered valid. Yet an `HtmlSize` appears to be defined to be *any* `u64` or `String`

In the interest of avoiding invalid values and clarifying the meanings of valid values, I'd personally go for a slightly more opinionated approach, with more explicit names, rejecting values that don't make sense as sizes. Going by your examples, I'd lean towards giving `HtmlSize` variants like `Pixels(u64)` (which would get serialized to a number), `Percentage(u64)` (where `HtmlSize::Percentage(50)` would get serialized as `"50%"`) and perhaps more options depending on what other kinds of values we expect to see (`Em(u64)`? Variants for CSS keywords like `max-content`, `auto`, or `inherit`? Other stuff entirely?)

Comment: Thank you. These are really good ideas. I don't need those fine-grained options at the moment, since the JSON provider currenty guarantes valid values, but I will consider implementing this as soon as I need it.